# Grails- How to render a view with a selected template?

Tags: templates, grails, controller

I created different tabs in a view with the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main-redesign" />
    <title>Account Settings</title>
</head>
<body>
<%-- global header --%>


<%-- tab navigation your network --%>
<g:render template="accountSettingNavigation"/>

<%-- main content area --%>
<div class="container account-setting">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
            <h3 class="page-title">ACCOUNT SETTINGS</h3>
            <%-- your network tab containers --%>
            <div class="tab-content mb-100">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="personalInformation">
                    <g:render template="personalInfo"
                              model="[user:user,editable:editable]" />
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="changePassword">
                    <g:render template="changePassword"/>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the changePassword template I have a form which includes 3 fields:
Current password
New password confirmation

After the user clicks on the "update password" the form is submitted to a controller to save the new password.

In have to render the view and to ensure that the changePassword template will be selected- How?

Answer (score 0):

Provide in your model, what tab is active and by that means decide, where to put the `active` css class.

Comment: U can see that by default the personalInfo template is active. How can I change it through the controller?

Comment: by making the e.g. id of the active tab part of your model in the controller

Comment: please check the fundamentals in the docs: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews

Answer (score 0):

1. first add hidden fields into the templates, which mark the tab
   (let say name="tabName" value"personalInformation")
2. in the controller you can access this field in
   params (params.tabName)
3. at the end of the controller put this
   field into the model
4. use this field in the gsp to decide what tab
   is active